# Does being sick affect creatine?

Tags: creatine, illness

I am fairly new to creatine (on my 3rd week) and I am starting to get a cold. Not from taking creatine but undoubtedly from my 3 children.

Should I continue taking creatine if I am sick? I won't be going to the gym if I'm sick.

I know water is hydration to regain health, but creatine also uses water. Will that be a direct conflict? As in, will my body be in a fight with the creatine to distribute the water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creatine is a very safe and well researched substance.  It's considered very safe and useful for being able to get more out of our training than we would without it.

It takes time for creatine to saturate into your muscles and be "loaded".  Some people do "loading" phases to get their creatine levels as high as possible, while others take a normal dose (about 5g / day) and will see their levels saturate, just at a longer time period.

With this in mind, it would be best to **not go off creatine** while sick.  It will not impact your sickness and will continue to help keep you muscle's creatine levels high for when you return back to training.  If you went off of it, you would need to go through the process of rebuilding your creatine levels and it would affect your performance on your return to training.

[Basic info about loading with creatine.](https://rpstrength.com/expert-advice/everything-you-need-to-know-about-creatine)